# Way to replace original way under Python Dataframe GroupBy

Tags: python, dataframe

I am a newbie in python. May i ask whether i should use groupby in python Dataframe to handle below situations?
I want redefine the week number and dont want use the original way. Thanks.

Expected Result

```
Week Redefine_Week
44   1
44   1
44   1
45   2
46   3
46   3
47   4
```

Original Way

```
df.loc[df['week_in_year'] == 44, 'week_no'] = 1
df.loc[df['week_in_year'] == 45, 'week_no'] = 2
df.loc[df['week_in_year'] == 46, 'week_no'] = 3
df.loc[df['week_in_year'] == 47, 'week_no'] = 4
```

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map`, `replace` should also work with an auxiliary dictionary:

```
aux = {44:1,45:2,46:3,47:4}
```

And now redefining the column:

```
df['Week'] = df['Week'].map(aux)
```